# asp.net mvc 3 - form post - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-post, connection-reset

I'm trying to make a form post page on asp.net mvc 3 application with 2500 input type "hidden" (because is like an preprocessed excel upload) with aprox 150 chars each input (aprox 400Kb of data) and on all browser i'm getting a connection reset error, the VS 2010 debugger is not firing an exception, I don't know what can I do!!!!

Ahh If I try the same thing but with 200 inputs hidden the page works well!

Any idea???? I'm running out of patience!

Comment: Are you bumping up against the max request length? Try increasing the maxRequestLength attribute in your web.config.

Comment: Yes I did it, I put 50Mb like these: 
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="51200" requestLengthDiskThreshold="51200"  />....

Comment: But, I read that default limit is 4Mb, seems enough for my form page

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the maxRequestLength attribute in your web.config

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <httpRuntime
    maxRequestLength="1048576"
    executionTimeout="3600" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```