# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in MVC 3 Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, connection-reset

I'm getting a connection reset error in my ASP.NET MVC3 app.  It seems to work on http, except that redirects to https which doesn't work.  I have tried fiddling with the timeout values as in [asp.net mvc 3 - form post - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927809/asp-net-mvc-3-form-post-err-connection-reset), but to no avail.  Has anyone seen and dealt with this sort of error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  I needed to re-create my SSL development self-signed certificate.  It expired not too long ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I was storing and retrieving binary data in / from my database, then upon a request for image data specifically, I was setting the Content-Length header variable to a size bigger than the requested image reflected (doh!), so the browser was expecting more bytes.  After two minutes or so it would throw the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET exception and clear the image.  I simply removed the header variable and I'm golden.